# How to add a submit button that does an HTTP Post

Tags: itext

How do I code the "CreateSubmitForm" command so that it generates a button that will submit an edited PDF back as HTTP POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first: submitting an edited PDF is only possible if the end user has Adobe Acrobat or if the PDF is Reader-enabled. In all other cases, you can only post the data (as a query string, as an FDF file, or as an XFDF file), you can not post the complete PDF from Adobe Reader.

By default, the submit button will be sent to the server as a HTTP POST. If you want HTTP GET, you need to set a flag. In other words: just create the button and you'll have an HTTP POST.

**Important:** the POST is performed from the PDF viewer, so it is very important to understand that you can not put any HTML in your Response. The PDF viewer will show an exception if you do. The PDF viewer expects either nothing (status code 204: No Content) or a stream of PDF (or correctly formatted FDF). All other content types will be rejected.

**Note:** although the question is tagged as an iTextSharp question, this answer is **not** limited to iTextSharp. It's just the way things are with PDF and Adobe Reader.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of information I needed to know. Thanks